# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: exec, csh

I have a java class in which I call a runshellscript method that will execute a script. It worked well with mysql but I cannot seem to find out why it wont work well with psql. Here is an excerpt of my runshell method:

```
public class RunShellScript {

public static void runShellScript (String unixCommand) 
{
 try {
     Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
     //Process process=runtime.exec(new String [] { "/bin/csh", "-c", unixCommand});
     Process process=runtime.exec(new String [] {unixCommand});
     InputStream stderr=process.getErrorStream();
     InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader (stderr);
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (isr);
     String line=null;
     System.out.println("<ERROR>");

     while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
         System.out.println(line);

     System.out.println(line);
     int exitVal=process.waitFor();
     System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitVal);
 }
 catch (Throwable t)
 {
     t.printStackTrace();
 }
```

the problem is that when i put this behind a mouse clicked event it says command not found. Here is the code beuind the mous event

```
private void jMenuItem13MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)    {                                         

    String shellCommand="vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/mysqlconnection.csh";
    RunShellScript.runShellScript(shellCommand);
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

The weird thing is that when I go directly to the directory where the script resides and type ./mysqlconnection the script works. But when i just type mysqlconnection is says command not found. Somehow it is not recognizing my script name as a command?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is similar to the problem I faced, when invoking a shell script (contains system & user created commands) from autosys [autosys -> shell -> Java -> ProcessBuilder]
`ProcessBuilder` will from a command and execute in Linux machine.
This worked when i log in to Linux box and execute the script but it didn't work when i invoke from autosys.
The actual problem is `$PATH` variable, which is not being set with the directory of the user created command.
I echo the $PATH variable when executing from Linux machine and Autosys in the shell script, $PATH variable is not set properly when executing from Autosys , after appending user command path to the $PATH variable it worked.
`which (cmd)` will return the directory of the command, append this directory with $PATH then it will work.

Try adding your script path to $PATH and execute from your application

Answer (score 0):

On unix-like systems, the shell only executes programs residing in the current directory if given an unambiguous path to it. This is to prevent an attacker from, say, putting a program named `ls` in your home directory which would execute instead of the actual `ls` program residing in `/bin/ls`. Thus, the current directory is excluded from the PATH.

Also, try moving

```
int exitVal=process.waitFor();
```

to above the `while` loop.

Comment: so should i add the path to where my csh script is to the path variable

Comment: You should use `./mysqlconnection` in your code instead of `mysqlconnection`

Comment: i tried...but it doesnt work. So you suggest the path that i assign my string variable to be should be vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/.mysqlconnection.csh";

Comment: What happens when you run `csh -c vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/mysqlconnection.csh`?

Comment: it did not work...it still give me the error command not found

Comment: you mean assign my sting the that value?

Comment: you mean run that directly from the terminal?

Comment: i dont think i should spceicy csh -c because that is already specified inthe string that i pass to runtime.exec

Comment: @rambokayambo Yes, I mean run it from the terminal.

Comment: @rambokayambo Did you try using `~/vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/mysqlconnection.csh` instead of `vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/mysqlconnection.csh`

Comment: hey i tried using the ~ infront and it gives me an error unknown user vobs

Comment: Are you sure you used `~/vobs` and not `~vobs`?

Comment: Also, one obvious thing, the file is named `mysqlconnection.csh` and not `mysqlconnection.<something-else>`, right?

Comment: yes that is ovbious it is mysqlconnection.csh and it didnt specify it as mysqlconnection.<something-else> so i dont think that is the problem. I did use ~vobs and it says unknown user vobs

Comment: i even tried to put /vobs...... but it just freezes up completely and i have to shut down netbeans

Comment: You need to use `~/vobs` With both the ~ AND the /

Comment: What is your username? It really, really shouldn't say that. What OS are you running?

Comment: /bin/csh -c vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/mysqlconnection.csh
i even tried that directly at the xterm and it works...but my java class is not executing the same string

Comment: ... Are you absolutely, completely sure that you are using both the tilde and the slash? Like, `~/vobs`????

Comment: i am running UNIX and my user name is pagola. if i put the ~ it means home directory and the script doesnt reside there...so i copied the files to my home directory and it still didnt work. I am very very very very positive i am using the tilde and the slash ....it still says unknown user

Comment: Where does the script reside then? Did you try using the Full Path to the script?

Comment: yes it shows in my above code that the script resides in vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation  it doesnt make sense to me

Comment: What is the full path though? If you go into the directory where mysqlconnection.c is and run `pwd`, what happens?

Comment: the full path is vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation

Comment: Are you sure you ran `pwd`? The full path should start with a `/`

Comment: So the full path is `/vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation`?

Comment: yup...this is very irritating

Comment: when i put /vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation is just hangs up and says <ERROR> but nothing else. The whole systems freezes and i have to do a complete shut down

Comment: @rambokayambo Okay, use the full path (with the `/`) and maybe try using the suggestion I just made in my edit?

Comment: what are you saying the edit you made...which edit?....i HAVE been using the full path with (/) and it just freezes up on me

Comment: @rambokayambo The edit I made to my question; the suggestion to move a line above the while loop.

Comment: NOPE....it still freezes up .....i dont think it even gets to that point...its gets to the <ERROR>

Comment: Does the script continue forever maybe?

Comment: i am starting to question the script...but i have run the script from the xterm and it outputs the result to the xterm and writes it to a log file just fine.....but when i try to use java it hangs up...i dont think the script has a problem

Comment: any new ideas..everything works from command line so i think its the java runtime .exec process

Comment: i got it to work by only leaving out the whole path but putting ~/mysqlconnection now at least it is reading the file

Comment: @rambokayambo Congrats! Sorry I couldn't be of more help; it's nice to have the on-site insight. Perhaps you should add your solution as an answer and accept it, so that others will see that this problem is solved.